# Why are my Jekyll defaults in config not working?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter

I am setting the defaults in my `_config.yml` file but they are not being picked up:

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "posts"
    values:
      layout: "post"
```

I am comparing it with another Jekyll site that I maintain where my sitewide frontmatter defaults are working as expected. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

I found that running `bundle update` (assuming you use Bundler) fixed the problem. I don't think that the gems were that old, but it looks like I upgraded liquid, which I suspect was the issue:

`Using liquid 2.6.2 (was 2.5.5)`

Comment: I don't think that was it. I seem to be using liquid 2.5.5 and that works as expected, with very similar settings.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know what happened then. Odd. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem: I had "jekyll serve" running locally and rebuilding continuously. Simply stopping it and re-running "jekyll serve" from scratch was the solution in my case: for certain changes, it seems that regeneration doesn't quite catch all the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `jekyll clean` before `serve` your server?

Or you can manually remove `_site` and `.jekyll-cache` folders and `.jekyll-metadata` file. Then Jekyll will generate site with `defaults`.